# get multiplication of two inputs and put it in another input with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, forms, input

[Preveiw1, here 'Total' fields are empty without auto multiplication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjlsh.png)

[Preveiw2, Here I fill the multiplication by myself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMkxN.png)

- this function collect all 'total' inputs of all rows and store the result it in another input.

```
var arr = document.getElementsByName('total[]');
    var tot=0;
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){ 
 //HERE before start collect total input value we need first to store the multiplication of QTE & PU. 
        if(parseFloat(arr[i].value))
            tot += parseFloat(arr[i].value); // here we collect all total input values
    }

    document.getElementById('Amount_Commission').value = tot; // store result
```

- this function is work well if I fill the total input by myself , but I need to do that with Js.

-this is one row for my form , the button (+) call JS function to generate another row with same attributes to store multiple row.

```
            <td><input type="text" name="QTE[]" id="QTE" class="form-control"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="PU[]" id="PU" class="form-control"></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="total[]" id="totali" 
             readonly ></td>
            <td><button type="button" id="add_btn" class="btn btn-primary">+</button></td> //generate another row
</tr>
```

Add new row function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#add_btn').on('click', function(){

    var html='';
    html='<tr>';
    html+='<td><input type="text" name="designation[]" class="form-control"></td>';
    html+='<td><input type="text" name="QTE[]" id="QTE" class="form-control"></td>';
    html+='<td><input type="text" name="PU[]" id="PU" class="form-control"></td>';
    html+='<td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="total[]" id="totali" readonly ></td>';
    
    html+='<td><button type="button"   id="remove" class="btn btn-danger">-</button></td>';
    html+='</tr>';
    $('tbody').append(html);

})
});

$(document).on('click', '#remove',function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Comment: Hi, can you ask in the form of a question. It's not clear what you're trying to get answered here thanks

Comment: When should the total of inputs be added to the `total`?

Comment: @TheBritishAreComing the solution must be inside the Js function. before the function collect "Total" field of each row. we need to put the multiplication of QTE & PU fields to Total field , then function witll get the Total field value . without that Total fields is empty.

Comment: @alireza i mention that inside the function with HERE . before starting collect each total input. because now the function collect empty value for total input. so we need first to put the multiplication , but we have here loop for each row as you see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are problems with your form the main one is `id`s. `id`s should be unique in the entire page while any time user clicks on the + button you create a duplicate id for inputs. (my understanding of your form structure.)

The solution is to add a number to the end of inputs id: QTE1, PU1, totali1
Then in your loop

```
const QTEValue = document.getElementById('QTE'+i).value
const PUValue = document.getElementById('PU'+i).value
const resultOfCalculation = QTEValue * PUValue
document.getElementById('totali'+i).value = resultOfCalculation
```

This should update the total input in the loop. Let me know if it didn't work

Note: you can do it using tagName by creating lists of inputs `QTEArr`, `PUArr`, and `totaliArr`. Then loop through them but it's very inefficient and loops through three arrays multiple times which may cause memory leakage in huge forms.

Update: Change row generation function to add numerical id as below.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  let incrementalRow = 1
  $('#add_btn').on('click', function(){

      let html='';
      html='<tr>';
      html+='<td><input type="text" name="designation[]" class="form-control"></td>';
      html+='<td><input type="text" name="QTE[]" id="QTE'+incrementalRow+'" class="form-control"></td>';
      html+='<td><input type="text" name="PU[]" id="PU'+incrementalRow+'" class="form-control"></td>';
      html+='<td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="total[]" id="totali'+incrementalRow+'" readonly ></td>';

      html+='<td><button type="button" id="remove'+incrementalRow+'" class="btn btn-danger">-</button></td>';
      html+='</tr>';
      
      $('tbody').append(html);
      incrementalRow++;

  })
});
$(document).on('click','[id^=remove]',function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
  <button type="button" id="add_btn" class="btn btn-primary">+</button>
</table>
```

Comment: you can see the function for generate new row , I added it now. if I add the const the new row generated will be different i guess . and I need this data to store it to database with controller in laravel

Comment: @SalahEddine I added the update which is a modified version of your function.

Comment: thank you , now we fix the duplication of id , but we still need to fill the total input with the multiplication of QTE & PU

Comment: @SalahEddine that's already in the answer. The part of code in answer should go to the` //HERE` line in your loop in the function.

Comment: remove row function doesnt work

Comment: @SalahEddine I fixed the remove function. But the code to get values and multiplication should work but you ned t match it with the rest of the function.

Comment: change `arr[i].value` to `document.getElementById('totali'+i).value`

Comment: I make some changes and now all things work well , but still cant remove the row with '-' button . this is the only error now

Comment: @SalahEddine Check out the code snippet, the whole function of adding and removing form items is there.

Comment: sorry I didnt noticed your edit . now it work . thank you